# Angular validar campo senha com FormGroup

Tags: html, angular, ionic3

Tenho o seguinte código:

**Código TS:**

```
...
onRegisterForm: FormGroup;
ngOnInit() {

    this.onRegisterForm = this._fb.group({
      nome: ['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required
      ])],      
      email: ['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required
      ])],
      senha: ['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(6)
      ])],
      confirm_senha: ['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required
      ])]
    });
  }
...
```

**Código HMTL:**

```
<ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Senha</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="{{isPassword ? 'password' : 'text' }}" [(ngModel)]="userData.senha" formControlName="senha" minlength="6"></ion-input>
        <button ion-button clear color="dark" type="button" class="btn-icon-eye" item-right (click)="showPassword()">
          <ion-icon name="ios-eye-outline" class="icon-eye" item-right></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-item>
      <p ion-text color="danger" class="has-error" *ngIf="onRegisterForm.get('senha').touched && onRegisterForm.get('senha').hasError('required')">Este campo é obrigatório.</p>
      <p ion-text color="danger" class="has-error" *ngIf="onRegisterForm.get('senha').hasError('minLength')">A senha deve conter no mínimo 6 caracteres.</p>
```

**Os dois validadores funcionam perfeitamente (o problema está na exibição das mensagens).**

Quando clico no campo e saio sem preencher o mesmo, é exibido a mensagem: *"Este campo é obrigatório."*. Porém, quando digito menos que seis caracteres a mensagem: *"A senha deve conter no mínimo 6 caracteres."* não é exibida!

**Analisando o código não conseguir encontrar o erro!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A algum tempo eu descobri o problema e esqueci de postar a resposta.

O erro estava em:

```
onRegisterForm.get('senha').hasError('minLength')
```

Onde `minLength` deveria estar em minusculo **minlength**

Desta forma:

```
onRegisterForm.get('senha').hasError('minlength')
```

Comment: Como você fez para fazer a validação de checagem de senha e confirm senha?

Comment: No HTML "<p ion-text color="danger" class="has-error" *ngIf="onRegisterForm.get('confirm_senha').touched && (onRegisterForm.get('confirm_senha').hasError('minlength') || confirm_senha != userData.senha)">Senha de confirmação incorreta.</p>" e no TS dentro do função de cadastro "if ( this.userData.senha != this.confirm_senha ) return false;".